# App Store Connect license agreement API

Tags: ios, itunesconnect

I manage many iOS App Store Connect (Itunes Connect) accounts and am interested in whether or not there is an API that exposes the status of the license agreement for an account, similar to how `https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/user/detail` exposes app name, contentProviderId, etc. as JSON. I can't find anything in apple docs, and it's annoying to find out the license agreement expired while trying to upload a build.
[image: apple developer agreement]

Apparently this is off-topic....please enlighten me as to where a post such as this should go?

Comment: I'm asking if an API exists which has nothing to do with programming. Seems there is no such site in the SE network, while I'm sure there are hundreds of engineers who could very quickly answer my question. Oh well.

Comment: Well there is https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ as well.